# SwiftUI - Dismiss second modal sheet not working

Tags: swiftui

My app displays an item detail in a modal sheet. The user can open edit mode within this modal sheet. So I'm using `.sheet(item) {}` to present a modal depending on the modal type (detail or edit). Everything is ok except two things:

#### Issue 1. Modal briefly disappears between state transitions

When going to Edit modal (has red background in example), I briefly see edit controls, then modal disappears and finally the edit screen is shown in the modal. Why does the modal disappear between states? Here is a slowed-down animation:

[image: animation]

#### Issue 2. Can't close second modal programmatically

When I'm in Edit modal, I can't close it programmatically. However the same code works in Detail modal

Here's an extracted part of the code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var modalType: ModalType?

    var body: some View {

        Button("Show details") {
            self.modalType = .details
        }
        .sheet(item: $modalType) { type in
            self.modal(for: type)
        }
    }

    private func modal(for type: ModalType) -> AnyView {

        switch type {
        case .details:
            return AnyView(
                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                    Text("Details").font(.largeTitle)
                    Button("Edit") { self.modalType = .edit }
                    Button("Close") { self.modalType = nil } // this works
                }
            )
        case .edit:
            return AnyView(
                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                    Text("Edit").font(.largeTitle)
                    Button("Close") { self.modalType = nil } // this doesn't work if opened from Details
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
            )
        }
    }
}

enum ModalType: String, Equatable, Identifiable {

    case details = "details"
    case edit = "edit"

    var id: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}
```

PS. I'm using xCode 11.5.